# Bitwise operators on different length BitArrays

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bitarray

I have 2 BitArray items and I need to know if any of bits are the same in each, "AND".
However, the length of the BitArrays can be different and ether one can be larger or smaller than the other.

How can I do an "AND" of two BitArrays, without getting an exception because of different sizes?
This is going to happen a lot, so I need it to be fairly quick.

Example

```
  int[] ids = new int[3];
  ids[0] = 1;
  ids[1] = 3;
  ids[2] = 5;
  BitArray bs1 = new BitArray(ids.Max()+1);
  for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); ++i)
  {
    bs1[ids[i]] = true;
  }


  ids[0] = 1;
  ids[1] = 59;
  ids[2] = 1111;
  BitArray bs2 = new BitArray(ids.Max()+1);
  for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); ++i)
  {
    bs2[ids[i]] = true;
  }

  ids[0] = 0;
  ids[1] = 5;
  ids[2] = 33;
  BitArray bs3 = new BitArray(ids.Max()+1);
  for (int i = 0; i < ids.Count(); ++i)
  {
    bs3[ids[i]] = true;
  }


  //if bs1 AND bs2 bitcount > 0 DisplayMessage("1 and 2 has some same items")
  //if bs1 AND bs3 bitcount > 0 DisplayMessage("1 and 3 has some same items")
  //if bs2 AND bs3 bitcount > 0 DisplayMessage("2 and 3 has some same items")
```

To solve my problem I modified the BitArray code and added the following

```
public static MyBitArray TruncateCopy(MyBitArray source, int size)
{
  MyBitArray dest = new MyBitArray(size);

  //copy all the arrays
  for (int i = 0; i < dest.m_array.Length; ++i)
  {
    dest.m_array[i] = source.m_array[i];
  }

  //remove any of the items over the given size
  for (int i = ((size % 32) + 1); i < 32; ++i)
  {
    dest.m_array[i >> 5] &= ~(1 << (i & 31));
  }

  return dest;
}

public bool HasCommonBits(MyBitArray comp)
{
  MyBitArray copied, other;

  if (this.Length < comp.Length)
  {
    other = this;
    copied = TruncateCopy(comp, this.Length);
  }
  else
  {
    copied = TruncateCopy(this, comp.Length);
    other = comp;
  }

  MyBitArray compareEq = copied.And(other);

  return (!compareEq.IsEmpty());
}

public bool IsEmpty()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < this.m_array.Length; ++i)
  {
    if (m_array[i] != 0)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}

public bool IsFull()
{
  //run through all the full sets
  for (int i = 0; i < this.m_array.Length - 1; ++i)
  {
    if (m_array[i] != -1) //-1 is all bits set in an integer
      return false;
  }

  //go through the partial one
  for (int i = 0; i < (this.Length % 32); ++i)
  {
    if (!this[i])
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

}

Comment: If they are different lengths, you need to first figure out how to make them the same, i.e. whther to remove the most or least significant (or other?) bit.

Comment: If they are different lengths, then there can't be any matching bits in the longer one.  Thus we can ignore the extra data in the longer BitArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define what you want to happen in case of differing lengths. Maybe you just want to compare the first `Math.Min(len1, len2)` elements. In that case write a `for` loop whose index variable ranges from 0 to `Math.Min(len1, len2)`. Compare the respective array elements in the loop body.

I examined `BitArray` with reflector. There is **no way** to trim it, or to perform a partial `And`. You're out of luck with this class. Replace it with a custom-written class that supports what you need. Writing a bit array is not especially hard.

Comment: I don't want to use a loop, the whole point of the BitArray is a very fast check.  I need a way to lob off the extra information from the longer BitArray and do the bitwize "AND"

Comment: Ok, I understand. I examined `BitArray` with reflector. There is no way to trim it, or to perform a partial `And`. You're out of luck with this class. Replace it with a custom-written class that supports what you need. Writing a bit array is not especially hard.

Comment: Can I quickly lengthen the shorter one with 0's. That would also work.

Comment: The size is fixed, alas. You can use Reflector to look at everything that is available. Note, that a custom BitArray would not be slower than the built-in one. It can even be faster.

Comment: Yea a custom one would be good, but I am just fairly new to c# and it would take me quite a while to figure out all the pieces.  Most other languages have nice bitset libraries, why doesn't c#, it seems that I can't even to a quick check to see if all the bits are 1 or 0 without a loop.

Comment: You can look at the mono source and use it as a starting point: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/BitArray.cs

Answer (score 0):

Completely revised based on this comment:

> The result bitarray of your example would be 01010. My original problem states that I need to see if any of the bits are the same. Thus the a resulting bitarray with any 1's would be True and all 0's would be False

```
BitArrray truncateCopyBA(BitArray source, int size)
{
    BitArray dest = new BitArray(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }

    return dest;
}

bool YourFunc(BitArray a, BitArray b)
{
    BitArray one, two;

    if (a.Length < b.Length)
    {
        one = a;
        two = truncateCopyBA(b, a.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        one = truncateCopyBA(a, b.Length);
        two = b;

        // If you want to see which bits in both arrays are both ones, then use .And()
        // If you want to see which bits in both arrays are the same, use .Not(.Xor()).
        BitArray compareEq = a.And(b);
        bool anyBitsSame=false;
        for(int i = 0; i < compareEq.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(compareEq.Get(i))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

I believe this is what you're looking for, but honestly your question is still quite vague after clarifications.

Comment: `BitArray.And` returns `BitArray`, not `bool`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Oops, brainfart on my part... will correct in a second

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Thanks for noting - I believe corrected version should now do it (albeit not as compact)

Comment: This doesn't help. I still need results if they are different lengths.

Comment: @runfastman Then please clarify your question with examples of cases and result in each...  i.e. how do you compare a set of 5 bits with a set of 15 bits - high level logic... then we can help with algorithm.

Comment: @runfastman You added just setup of values, not explanation how you want to have them compared.  eg, how do these two suppose to compare `0101010 and 010101011111`? By your requirement, are these equal or not?

Comment: I am not looking for equal, I am checking for any "1" bits after doing and "AND" operator.  So your example would be "True", 01101 and 100101111 would be "False"

Comment: @runfastman, hold on, that doesn't make sense.  I'm asking what do you expect result to be of `01010 AND 0101011111 = ?`.  I.e. how do you expect result to be when two BitArrays are of different size?

Comment: The result bitarray of your example would be 01010.  My original problem states that I need to see if any of the bits are the same. Thus the a resulting bitarray with any 1's would be True and all 0's would be False.

Comment: @runfastman I'm not sure if I still understand your requirement as it is still quite vague, but if I understood your right, see the revised answer.